# T-SQL-Update T1 Balance+Amt from T2-Multiple Rows in T2 match T1-there is case logic on Amt

Tags: t-sql, sql-update

This is probably simple and I'm missing it - I'm tempted to use a cursor - but it seems too simple to have to go that route just yet - hopefully someone here can help.

Here is my code and sample data:

```
drop table if exists Customer
create table Customer (
ID int not null,
[Name] nvarchar(20),
Balance money not null
)

drop table if exists Transact
create table Transact (
ID int not null,
CustomerID int not null,
[Type] int not null,  -- 1 = payment, 2 = invoice
Amount money not null
)

insert into Customer
    Values (1, 'Bob', 100), (2, 'John', 500)

insert into Transact
    Values (1, 1, 2, 50), (2, 1, 1, 25), (3, 1, 2, 10),
    (4, 2, 2, 100), (5, 2, 1, 50), (6, 2, 1, 200)

select * from Customer
select * from Transact
```

This gives this result:

```
ID  Name    Balance
1   Bob     100.00
2   John    500.00
```

and

```
ID  CustomerID  Type    Amount
1   1           2       50.00
2   1           1       25.00
3   1           2       10.00
4   2           2       100.00
5   2           1       50.00
6   2           1       200.00
```

What I want to do is add the Amount values from the Transact table to the the Balance column of the Customer table. This is the code I tried:

```
update Customer
set Customer.Balance = Customer.Balance + t.Amount
from Transact t
where Customer.ID = t.CustomerID
```

But this is giving this result - not what I want:

Customer Table:

```
ID  Name    Balance
1   Bob     150.00
2   John    600.00
```

I am trying to get this result:

```
ID  Name    Balance
1   Bob     135.00
2   John    350.00
```

I assume in the Update that the Customer Balance is fixed and even if it iterated across all the matching Transact records - basically the last one wins.

Thanks in advance!

PS - To Add more info here, this cursor approach does what I want, but I am trying to find a set-based approach using Update and not a cursor. But to show the logic needed and the result:

```
Declare @CustomerID int
Declare @TransType int
Declare @Amount money
declare trans_cursor cursor for
    select  t.CustomerID, t.[Type], T.Amount
    from    Transact t
open trans_cursor
fetch next from trans_cursor into @CustomerID, @TransType, @Amount
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        Update C
        SET C.Balance = C.Balance +
            (case when @TransType = 2 then @Amount
            when @TransType = 1 then (-(@Amount))
        end)
        from Customer C
        where C.ID = @CustomerID
        fetch next from trans_cursor into @CustomerID, @TransType, @Amount
    end
close trans_cursor
deallocate trans_cursor
```

which gives the expected result:

```
ID  Name    Balance
1   Bob     135.00
2   John    350.00
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE c
SET c.Balance = c.Balance + t.Amount
FROM Customer AS c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 2 THEN Amount ELSE Amount * -1 END) AS Amount FROM Transact
    WHERE CustomerID = c.ID
    GROUP BY CustomerID 
) t
```